# How to update layout after hiding a view

Tags: ios, objective-c

There are 3 **ImageView** in my constraint based layout, i have to remove second ImageView in some scenario, i tried with hiding the image view but the issue is there is space between **ImageView1** and **ImageView3** and layout is not getting updated after hiding one of the view, i tried some of the solution given on stack overflow but not get resolved.Tried something like this

```
(void)viewDidLoad {

   [super viewDidLoad];
    Imageview2.hidden = YES;
   [self setNeedsLayout]; 
 }
```

I also tried `[self.view LayoutIfNeeded]` but no changes same result. Is there any better way of doing this. Please help me out of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since its a constraint based layout, you have to set the width and height constraints to 0 along with setting the leading, trailing spaces to 0 of the second image view as well (assuming a horizontal layout) and if its vertical, the top and bottom spacing of the second view to 0. As even if the `UIImageView` is hidden, the constraints are still active.

**Alternatively**, a much simpler approach is to put all three items into a `UIStackView` and then hiding the required elements. Stack view handles all of this for you while respecting `autoLayout`. As far as i know it adds constraints of width and height to be 0 when you hide an object inside the `UIStackView`

I recommend using a `UIStackView` **if** your app provides support for **iOS 9 and above only**.

Answer (score 0):

While hiding your imageView/View just set constant height 0.

```
_view.yourImageView.hidden = YES;
_view.yourImageViewConstraintHeight.constant = 0;
```